# How do you use two mappings to traverse a 2-tuple in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, traversal

I have a monad `m` that supports the following operation:

```hs
someName :: (t1 -> m u1) -> (t2 -> m u2) -> ((t1, t2) -> m (u1, u2))
```

In something more like English: given a mapping that could be used with `bind` to turn an `m t1` into `m u1` and another mapping for another pair of types, return such a mapping for pairs of the two types.

**Does this concept have a name?** Is it well-defined for all monads? Only some? None, and I have my facts wrong for the one I'm working on?

---

This is reminiscent of the [`traverse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286598/1505451) operation on `Traversable`s, except there are two mappings involved. Plus, `traverse` for 2-tuples only seems to apply the mapping to the second element:

```hs
ghci> f a = Just (a + 1)
ghci> traverse f (0, 1)
Just (0,2)
ghci> traverse f ("Hello", 1)
Just ("Hello",2)
```

Comment: Looks like a special case of an arrow: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [`bitraverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Bitraversable.html#v:bitraverse) and comes standard with your favorite compiler.

Comment: Indeed it seems to be, thanks!

Comment: It's a bit overkill though, since tuples are the unit-bitraversable.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Could you unpack that a tad for me? What does "unit-bitraversable" mean? Why would that make `bitraverse` overkill? What is the exact-kill solution?

Answer (score 6):

All monads have this operation. In fact, all applicative functors have this operation:

```hs
someName :: Applicative m => (t1 -> m u1) -> (t2 -> m u2) -> ((t1, t2) -> m (u1, u2))
someName f1 f2 = \(t1, t2) -> (,) <$> f1 t1 <*> f2 t2
```

For this reason, I doubt it has any special name, or any interesting properties beyond those of `Applicative` more generally.